# I'm trying to get 4 files from a directory with an specific extension each one

Tags: python, list

```
files = [
    f for f in listdir(input_path)
    if path.isfile(path.join(input_path, f))
]
if files:
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xml"):
            xml_filename = input_path + file
        elif file.endswith(".csv"):
            csv_filename = input_path + file
        elif file.endswith(".osgb"):
            osgb_filename = input_path + file
        elif file.endswith(".xodr"):
            xodr_filename = input_path + file
```

I'm trying to get 4 files from a directory with an specific extension each one but my solution looks kinda ugly you smart guys may have a clever solution ;D

Comment: Is it important that the results end up as variables? Would a dict of `{"csv":the_csv_file, ...}` work? That would make cleaner code.

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](/q/1373164/4518341), [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](/q/60208/4518341) (e.g. `match file.rsplit('.', 1)[1]: case 'xml': ...`)

Comment: Sidenote: `for file in files` implies `if files`

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `glob.glob()`

```
from glob import glob
import os

xml_filename = glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.xml'))[0]
csv_filename = glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.csv'))[0]
osgb_filename = glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.osgb'))[0]
xodr_filename = glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.xodr'))[0]
```

Note that this code assumes that there's at least one of each file type in the directory. You can use `try/except` to catch the `IndexError` if `glob()` doesn't return any matches.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce code count if you move your result into a collection that can be filled in a loop. With individual variables, you need code per variable for the assignment. Using a dictionary and the standard `pathlib` module, your code could be

```
from pathlib import Path
files = {path.suffix[1:]:path for path in Path(input_path).iterdir()
    if path.suffix in {".csv", ".xml", ".osgb", ".xodr"}}
```

Now `xml_filename` is `files["xml"]`.